# How to check variable value on console in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to check variable value in console I have tried everything but I am not getting the value in console.

```
 // Here I want to check $cart_id value before if Statement
 echo "Cart Id Before If Statement:" . $cart_id;
```

The above line is not working because the page add_cart skip and I am not able to check the value like I usually do. So I need to check this value on cosole like

```
console.log($cart_id);
```

But when I check console the console is showing empty. But When I click on network then I open preserve log then my file add_cart.php is showing and I am able to see cookie as well as form data but I have no idea how to check $cart_id in console or in any way.

I also tried in my helper.php class

```
function debug_to_console( $data ) {
$output = $data;
if ( is_array( $output ) )
    $output = implode( ',', $output);

echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' ); 
</script>";
}
```

And call it before my if statement

```
debug_to_console($cart_id);
```

But above also not working for me. I am not able to check the result of $cart_id before if statement. Nothing show on console.

```
if ($cart_id != '') {

}else{

$items_json = json_encode($item);
$cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
$db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}') ");
$cart_id = $db->insert_id;
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);
}
```

Your valuable suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: When you inspect the page source in the browser, is your call to `console.log()` there at all?  What does it look like?

Comment: Showing just > symbol

Comment: try `echo "<script type="application/javascript">....`

Comment: Try to echo this function `(function showUp(){
console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );
})()`

Comment: *«the page add_cart skip»* ?? What does it mean? Have you look form the PHP error log? It's a file named `error_log`, usually located in the same folder where the file is... Or in the folder where the file "includer" is. On the PHP server, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its only to debug your application code, you can simply add a dump in your php code before if statement, like -

```
var_dump($cart_id);die();

if ($cart_id != '') {...}
```

As, the call is ajax, you will have an http call generated in network tab. Opening that select Response. There you will be able to see the value of $cart_id. That can be found as shown in below image -

[image]

Comment: Exactly I want this but not working for me. When I click the browser page do not open add_cart.php only ajax call is happening and the browser page go index.php after click. And on console when I check add_cart.php response nothing showing.